# Puppeteer cant find element with matching id user[real_name]

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

```
await page.$eval('#user[real_name]', el => el.value = realName);
```

That is my code and even tho when I inspect the element I see the correct ID puppeteer says it cant find it why? Is it because of the brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so if anyone has a problem the reason is the brackets
So just change the code to this:

```
await page.$eval('[id="user[real_name]"]', (el, realName) => el.value = realName, realName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant to use the `==` instead ot the single `=`

```
await page.$eval('[id="user[real_name]"]', el => el.value == realName);
```